Universal footprint for 16 bit ISA slot
8 bit ISA slot footprint is quite simple: 62 plated holes positioned in two rows 2.54 mm apart from each other. Any generic card edge connector with matching spacing and number of pins would fit.

16 bit ISA slot footprint is similar with addition of 36 more similar holes in two rows with similar spacing. The added rows continue of the existing two and are separated by 10.16 mm from them. This way either a specialized 98 pin connector can be used, or two generic connectors (62 pin and 36 pin) would also fit.

In the space between the two connectors can be used for 6 more holes with similar spacing. This would would extend the possible connector options to three: a specialized 98 pin connector, a 62 pin and a 36 pin generic connectors, or a 104 pin generic connector.

Was such footprint ever used for ISA cards? Was there something in the ISA specification preventing the use of a 104 pin connector? Even short 8 bit cards should be inserted correctly in a longer slot, because they are held in place with a screw. I found a similar "keyless" PCI footprint with 124 pins (instead of the regular 120 pins + a key), and I wonder why this was done to PCI, but not to ISA.

Never underestimate the ability of a user to somehow get the pins in the wrong holes...

Yes, 8 bit ISA card can be installed incorrectly in a 104 pin slot if it's missing the bracket. But if such card is missing a bracket, it can also be installed backwards in any other ISA slot, so...

There is a 104-pin ISA-based standard, PC/104, but the connectors are completely different.

@tpimh It can also be faulty inserted with a bracket mounted as the bracket fitting has more wiggle room than the divider between two contacts is wide. The bracket is not meant to hold secure electric connection, but to offer mounting space for external connectors while keeping the case (somewhat) RF-tight.

Even if the bracket is present, a lot of people wouldn't install the screw (too lazy, no screwdriver handy, lost it down the heater vent, etc). It's nice if the card still works reliably. Yes, you could say it's user error, but better not to have to field those tech support calls in the first place.

What would be the point of having 6 more pins? What signals would you want to connect them to?


Was such footprint ever used for ISA cards?

While it's hard to answer any 'was it ever' question, this is a clear no, as it's unreliable with 8 bit cards.

Was there something in the ISA specification preventing the use of a 104 pin connector?

No, Why should they add restrictions not asked for?

Even short 8 bit cards should be inserted correctly in a longer slot, because they are held in place with a screw.

Not really. For one, cards may come without a bracket, so no way to place a screw, but more important, the tolerances of that bracket are more than what's good for the contacts. That means without the break at the slot it's incredible easy to faultily insert an 8 bit card.

I found a similar "keyless" PCI footprint with 124 pins (instead of the regular 120 pins + a key), and I wonder why this was done to PCI, but not to ISA.

In case of PCI the coding is about the card voltage, 3.3 or 5 Volt. This works as position 12/13 (3.3V) and 50/51 (5V) all carry GND. A footprint with all 62x2 soldering points doesn't mean there are any sockets using all connections. All it does is to allow fitting either slot type, depending on what the customer wants. Boards using such are usually configurable for either (or both) configurations

(Image taken from Wikipedia)
Also, while universal cards working with either voltage are defined, they have to carry both notches, otherwise they wouldn't fit either slot.
Likewise, note that 64-bit PCI-extension works the very same way as 16-bit ISA did - by adding a second connector and requiring a notch. There is no version without - at least none that conforms to standards.
Long story short: A footprint only tells how many holes should be drilled and pads placed - not what device can or will be placed there.

So essentially it’s about providing a mechanical constraint to ensure the contacts line up — since 8-bit cards had a short connector, the notch securing that had to be preserved.

Worth noting that PCIe, which does permit cards that only partially fill a slot, has an alignment notch in the slot.

@Mark PCI-E works the same way as ISA and PCI by having at least one section filled to guarantee right alignment.
